# Exponential Complex Number

Tags: complex-numbers

I need assistance in solving the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcGLD.jpg

I am not very sure on how to remove the exponential to convert it into complex numbers and get the arguments in the end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/)!  It would help if you could provide us with the steps that you have tried so far to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This notation is called polar notation and is a very nice way to write complex numbers. In front of the exponential there is the length of the vector and in the exponent, there is the argument multiplied by i.
$$
re^{i\theta}
$$

The nice this about it is that calculating powers of imaginary numbers, as well as multiplication and division is very easy.
$$
z_1^2 = r^2e^{i\theta*2}\\
z_1*z_2 = r_1*r_2e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)}\\
z_1/z_2 = r_1/r_2e^{i(\theta_1-\theta_2)}
$$
In this case the lengths are 1 so they are not visible and the arguments of $z_1$ and $z_2$ respectively are $\pi/4$ and $-\pi/3$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great explanation. So for my question 3a) it's 3pi/12 and -8pi/12 right? so the answer is -5pi/12 but for the next argument which is the division one, i got 9pi/12 divided by -4pi/12, which is not right as the answer is -11pi/12. What went wrong here?

Comment: You don't have $9\pi/12$ divided by $-4\pi/12$. When dividing numbers in polar form, you subtract the arguments, not divide. So you have $9\pi/12 + 4\pi/12$ (the plus is due to the fact that you are subtracting a negative number which is equivalent to adding a positive). This yields $13\pi/12$, which is equal to $-11\pi/12$ after subtracting $2\pi$ from it.

Comment: Yep that's what i meant,  9π/12+4π/12 and I get 13π/12. But why would i need to subtract 2π and how did 13π became -11π just because of 2π?

Comment: Because the argument is an angle. Both $13\pi/12$ and $-11\pi/12$ is correct, however the latter one is a bit nicer since it is a proper fraction. You can subtract and add any multiple of $2\pi$ to an angle and its still going to be the same, draw it if you have trouble picturing it. However its preferred to keep the angles between $-2\pi$ and $2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @QingYong If this solved your problem you can accept the answer to the left of the post so that people know its solved